# React-Native firebase push notification redirect to a specific screen when click on a notification

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to make my push notification to be able to take me to a specific screen once its clicked. As of now the push notification does nothing when clicked except opening the app if its in the background. I have searched online, and trial & error for two days now to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

I do not have code ready. I'm kind of new in React-Native

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541163/how-to-navigate-screen-on-notification-open-in-react-native-with-one-signal

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on "https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/overview". This will help you. Through this you can redirect to app on click of notification and you can manage other screens redirection too. :)